# Batch file to output last line of findstr

Tags: batch-file, tail, findstr

I am trying to find a list of machines in files in folders, and print out the last line of the output only.

```
@echo off
for /f %%a in (computers.txt) do findstr /xs "%%a" unhealthy.txt
pause
```

*The computers.txt file has a list of 300 machines.*

I want that to output only the last line of each instance it finds.

Right now the command displays and outputs all instances of the computer name, not just the tail end. I've tried to use "tail for Windows" but am getting errors as well.

Current output:

```
2013\10-Oct\28\unhealthy.txt:WIN57505
2013\10-Oct\29\unhealthy.txt:WIN57505
2013\10-Oct\30\unhealthy.txt:WIN57505
2013\10-Oct\31\unhealthy.txt:WIN57505
2013\11-Nov\1\unhealthy.txt:WIN57505
2013\11-Nov\4\unhealthy.txt:WIN57505
2013\11-Nov\5\unhealthy.txt:WIN57505
2013\11-Nov\6\unhealthy.txt:WIN57505
```

I only want:

`2013\11-Nov\6\unhealthy.txt:WIN57505`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
for /f %%a in (computers.txt) do (
    set "line="
    for /f "tokens=*" %%b in ('findstr /xs "%%a" *') do set "line=%%b"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    echo(!line!
    endlocal
)
pause
endlocal
```

Comment: Thank you - this worked like a charm. Changed the input of findstr to my txt file.

Answer (score 0):

```
setLocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f %%a in (computers.txt) do for /f "tokens=*" %%A in ('findstr /xs "%%a"') do set lastFound=%%A
echo !lastFound!
```