# Backup from shadow copy

Tags: windows, batch-file, backup, command-prompt, shadow-copy

So, I want to make backups from the shadow-copy using batch-script. That's what I have so far:

```
vssadmin list shadows | findstr /C:"Volume da Cópia de Sombra"
```

Output:

```
     Volume da Cópia de Sombra: \\?\GLOBALROOT\Device\HarddiskVolumeShadowCopy1
     Volume da Cópia de Sombra: \\?\GLOBALROOT\Device\HarddiskVolumeShadowCopy2
     Volume da Cópia de Sombra: \\?\GLOBALROOT\Device\HarddiskVolumeShadowCopy5
```

I need to get only the path in the last line returned by findstr, but I really don't know how I'll accomplish it.

And after getting the path and add a `\`to the end (it will only make the symbolic link if the path ends with a `\`) make a symbolic link to it.

```
mklink c:\shadowcopy /d %path%
```

So, I'm lost in the middle of it.

I found this question with an answer:

[Batch file to output last line of findstr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21007472/batch-file-to-output-last-line-of-findstr)

But man, batch syntax is a mess and I don't understand a line of code in the answer to adapt it to my project.

Can someone help me and explain in details what i need to do (or the code, if you provide it) so I can understand what I'm doing instead of just paste and copy and, who knows, make some improvements/changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you want to capture the output of a command, use `for /f`.  I suggest that `?` would be a convenient delimiter in this case.

This snippet would create links for all the shadow copies.

```js
if not exist c:\shadowcopy md c:\shadowcopy
for /f "tokens=2 delims=?" %%I in ('vssadmin list shadows ^| find "GLOBALROOT"') do (
    mklink /d c:\shadowcopy\%%~nxI \\?%%I\
)
```

This snippet would create a single link from the final matched line of the shadow list.

```js
for /f "tokens=2 delims=?" %%I in ('vssadmin list shadows ^| find "GLOBALROOT"') do (
    set "target=\\?%%I\"
)
mklink /d c:\shadowcopy %target%
```

See the difference?  In the first code block, `mklink` fires on every iteration of the `for /f` loop and creates many symlinks; whereas in the second block, `set` overwrites the value stored in `%target%` on every iteration. `mklink` runs *outside* the loop, and therefore creates only one symlink.  That's the secret sauce you're looking for I think.

In a cmd console, enter `help for` for more information on `for /f` loops.

Comment: Why the `^` before the pipe?

Comment: Because the pipe isn't quoted in double quotes and would be treated as a literal command separator prematurely.  Try it without and see what happens.  Without, the cmd interpreter treats the pipe as the end of the `for` command, rather than the end of the `vssadmin` command as we want.  Escaping the pipe with a caret delays the evaluation of the pipe until the `vssadmin` command is run.

Comment: Uhmm, I get it. So, `^` is the escaping character in batch? Makes sense, since `\\`` is widelly used in batch. Thanks a lot man. EDIT: Had to edit becase `\\` is a escaping character here, so needed to add double xD

Comment: @Rafael, the FINDSTR commnd uses the \ for escaping in regular expressions.  And if you need to escape a percent symbol then you double the percent symbols.  Just a couple of the idiosyncrasies with batch.

Comment: That is just perfect